# ASP MVC send an Array object to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP MVC for my university coursework. However I have encountered a problem, before I was sending too many AJAX requests which was causing my page to take way too long to load. Therefore I thought I could improve the situation by sending the arrays from the database to the view and then put them into my jquery function inline.

So here is how it looks I have my simple model:

```
public class NewBooking
    {
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> parks { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in my controller I set the parks with information from the database as you can see here:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new NewBooking();

            var parks = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString").Query("SELECT * FROM Park");

            var output = from o in parks
                         select new { parkID = o.parkID, parkName = o.parkName };
            model.parks = output.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

Now, this returns to the view all the information I am expecting, as you can see below if I simply called the model parks in the view:

```
@model build_01.Models.Timetabler.NewBooking
@{
    @Model.parks
}
```

I know this method wouldn't however with a for loop it works fine, now to my issue; I'm trying to call a JavaScript function and pass this array to it.

```
$(document.ready(function () {
        slotAvailability(@Model.parks);
    }));
```

Is there something I can do to this `@Model.parks` to be able to send it to the function? Kind of like how I would do JSON if I was using AJAX.

As it stands trying to call it like this gives me this error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I can see why, if I was to inspect element I can see that the function parse looks like this:

```
slotAvailability(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[&lt;&gt;f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Object,System.Object]]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Json.Encode` function. Also make sure tha you close your parenthesis at the proper place, after `document`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.parks));
    slotAvailability(parks);
});
```

Also using `dynamic` seems like a bad design here. You don't get any Intellisense. You'd rather have a view model:

```
public class ParkViewModel
{
    public int ParkId { get; set; }
    public int ParkName { get; set; }
}
```

and then your `NewBooking` model:

```
public class NewBooking
{
    public IEnumerable<ParkViewModel> Parks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This looks like this in the console: $(document.ready(function () {
        var parks = [{"parkID":1,"parkName":"Central"},{"parkID":2,"parkName":"East"},{"parkID":3,"parkName":"West"}];
        slotAvailability(parks);
    })); which looks better but i get this as an error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Yes, that's because you have invalid javascript. You should close your parenthesis after `document`. See my updated answer. Basically you should have `$(document)` and then invoke the `ready` function on the result of it.

Comment: haha oh yeah lol, thank you! Love the new setup too thanks very much!

Comment: Also the class ParkViewModel I can put that in the same file as NewBooking?

Comment: Standard C# convention dictates that each class goes into a separate file with the same name as the class. So you would rather have a `ParkViewModel.cs` containing this view model.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, when I create the new model this approach no longer works:

var parks = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString").Query("SELECT * FROM Park");

            var output = from o in parks
                         select new { parkID = o.parkID, parkName = o.parkName };
            model.parks = output.ToList();

Comment: Sure, you need to project your LINQ query to the correct type: `select new ParkViewModel { ParkID = o.parkID, ParkName = o.parkName }` instead of using anonymous type as you currently do.

Comment: okay, but how would i then return it to the view? I mean i can't now use model.parks = output.ToList() followed with return View(model); I know i'm probably thick but I can't work out how i need to adjust this to send it to the view correctly

Comment: The way you are returning your view model to the view shouldn't be impacted. Since your main view model is `NewBooking` you simply `return View(model);` as you already have. It is just the `Parks` collection that gets strongly typed instead of using some dynamic types. So you would assign the `Parks` property of your model from the result of your query: `model.Parks = output.ToList();` assuming of course you have projected your `output` to the correct view model as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: Haha the whole time the problem was a caps lock